# BPEL input variable translation

Tags: bpel

I am working on a web service integration with Bpel and I'm still looking for the best way to translate my variable values within these web services.

What I need to do is to create some kind of validation table where I can decide if my request service has for example: variable value='1', it translates this value to the response service with variable value='CO1C'.

I was trying with XSLTransformation but I don't quite understand the syntax of this programming language.

Does anyone know what is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the problem correctly. Assuming you want to translate from a certain value to another value based on a static map, you could initialize a translation variable with a map like this:

```
<map>
  <value key="1">CO1C</value>
  <value key="2">...</value>
  ...
</map>
```

The XPath expression `/map/value[@key='1']/text()` will then return `CO1C`.

Then you can replace `'1'` by another variable, say $mykey:

```
<assign>
  <copy>
    <from>$transmap/map/value[@key=$mykey]/text()</from>
    <to>$myval</to>
  </copy>
</assign>
```

Please note that this code is untested, so it may need some tweaking before it works but should give some hints how you could solve your (assumed) problem.